# Azure DevOps Query Dependencies

Tags: azure-devops, dependency-management

Using Azure DevOps Dependency Tracking plugin from Microsoft AppStore...

**Story 1**

I am looking for technical design details that tell me how Dependency data is written to the ADO database so that I may query those fields and relationships directly.

**Story 2**

As a Product Portfolio Manager, I want to create a Query to create a list of Dependencies across my entire Product portfolio so that I can drive dependency management across product teams within my portfolio.

**Assumptions**

I'm assuming that the plugin

a) extends existing Entities and relationships within ADO

b) creates a unique Dependency Entity within ADO.

c) Dependency data can be accessed through Odata (PowerBI, Excel ADO Add-in)

Comment: Hello Chris, please test and check whether my answer can help you~ In addition, could you please elaborate on what you're doing with this plugin? By "dependency" do you mean something in [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/extensions/dependency-tracker?view=azure-devops)? Or is it about Azure DevOps interacting with Microsoft's other software? I can't find the url to download this plugin, would you please provide it?

Comment: In the scenario, we're linking PBI/Stories from one Azure DevOps backlog to a different Azure DevOps backlog.

Comment: You can find the Plugin on the Microsoft AppStore (Microsoft Labs)
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-eswm.dependencytracker

Answer (score 0):

> I am looking for technical design details that tell me how Dependency data is written to the ADO database so that I may query those fields and relationships directly.

Maybe you can try [fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler/fiddler-classic) or other Web Debugging Proxy Tool to check the requests Dependency Tracking plugin sent to get dependencies.

Here are the detailed steps to use fiddler:

1. Launch your fiddler and choose “Tools” -> “Clean WinINET cache”, then go to “Tools” menu -> “Options” -> HTTPS tab  -> enable “Decrypt HTTPS Traffic” ->select “…from all processes” in the dropdown list, then close the fiddler.
2. Launch and minimize Fiddler to tray, then send your query.
3. Check the requests to find out which ones you need.

Also, you can look for clues in the API references:

1. [REST API browser for Azure DevOps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/?view=Azure%20DevOps).
2. [.NET API browser for Azure DevOps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/?view=azure-devops-dotnet).

Answer (score 0):

ADO Queries have a built-in feature to list linked items.

1. In Queries, create a new query.
2. Directly under the Editor tab, select Type of Query then
   a) Select "Work Items and Direct Links"
   b) Default type is "Flat List of Work Items"
   c) There is also "Tree of Work Items".
3. A separate set of criteria appear below the main query.
4. Select one of the Filter Options:
   a) Only return items that have matching links
   b) Return all top level items
   c) Only return items that do not have matching links
5. Then select one type of link
   a) Return links of any type
   b) Return selected link types